# Get the highest value of an array object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, arrayobject

```
$rank_points = Rank_points::select('dep1_point','dep2_point','dep3_point')
->where('user_id',$user->user_id)
->first();
```

The $rank_points object has 3 elements:

```
dep1_point: 31
dep2_point: 35
dep3_point: 33
```

I just need to get the index name with the highest value. I struggled with different ways but could not get the exact.

Experts please help me on this! thanks in advance.

Comment: You can answer your own question, your answer can help others.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lord! solved it at last!

```
$rank_points = Rank_points::select('dep1_point','dep2_point','dep3_point')
->where('user_id',$user->user_id)
->first()->toArray();

$max_point = max($rank_points);
$key = array_search($max_point, $rank_points);
```